# Character Workflow for Production Pipeline

Tags: materials, rigging, workflow, linked-data, library-overrides

I'm working on a concept for a production pipeline that is used by a team of artists.

This is my planned structure.
[image]

I want to have separate files for modeling, texturing/shading and rigging to be able to split workloads between artists. Every subtask has working files and a _release-file with the latest usable version. These release-files should be used to build one character_release.

What are streamlined solutions to merge the 3 subtask release-files into one final release-file? (Get the geo of the model-file, the materials from the tex-file and the rig + weights from the rig-file.)

Comment: This will probably get closed as an opinion-based question; but it could easily be edited to make it less so by changing the last paragraph to look for "what are easy solutions" rather than "what is the most 'easy".

Comment: This is often done with library files and linking